# FFmpeg av_read_frame returns a size but no data?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, managed-c++, libavcodec, libavformat

I have written some C code to access ffmpeg and wrapped it in a C++/CLI (.NET managed) class. The program fetches a live video stream and extracts frames and converts them to PNG files.

Unfortunately the images that are saved to disk are always black (opening them in Notepad++ shows that they are full of nulls).

I am using the assemblies aformat/codec-55.dll and the development headers and libs for compilation from ffmpeg-20131120-git-e502783-win64-dev. The whole project is compiled using Managed C++ (Cpp/cli) .NET 4.0 for 64-bit.

After some investigation the problem appears to be that av_read_frame fills the AVPacket->size value correctly, but the AVPAcket->data is always null. When the frame is finished (got==1) then the data for the AVFrame is just a matrix of nulls. :(

Here is the code:
[Example code (sorry, but it didnt paste well into SO)](http://pastebin.com/3nSXGWQ8)

I think the problem is at line 34 when the packet is returned like so:
[image: size is set but data is empty]

Please, how can I get this to work? What have I done wrong?

Comment: Your `pkt.data` is not NULL, it's just the first byte is '\0'. So probably you should check `pkt.data`'s contnet first, and then check `frame`, then check `rgbFrame`, and last check `outPacket`, to see at which step the content becomes invalid.

Comment: Have you tried initializing `pkt` first?  E.g. `AVPacket pkt = {0};`.  At present it could be filled with junk on the call to `av_read_frame`

Comment: The packet may be correct, if the first of the 143 content bytes is a '\0'. Did you try to record all the video frames? It may be that the first frame of your video is really a black frame.

Answer (score 1):

Decoding part seems fine to me. I am not so sure about the encoding & saving to PNG. Why don't you try to just dump `(frame->linesize*frame->height)` bytes from `frame->data` to disk with fwrite and have a look to it with Irfanview (for instance)?